# Accessing Method that Returns String Format in a Driver?

Tags: java, string, format, driver

Here is the method in the driver:

```
    public class CustomerTest {

        private static int customerCounter = 0;

        public static boolean test1(){
            System.out.println("Test1: create a customer");
            Customer c = new Customer("Alice", "Smith");
            customerCounter++;
            return c.getName().equals("Alice Smith") && customerCounter == c.getCustomerID();
        }
            public static boolean test2() {
    System.out.println("Test2: create two customers");
    Customer c1 = new Customer("Alice", "Smith");
    Customer c2 = new Customer("Bob", "Simpson");
    customerCounter += 2;
    return c1.getName().equals("Alice Smith") && (customerCounter - 1) == c1.getCustomerID()
        && c2.getName().equals("Bob Simpson") && (customerCounter) == c2.getCustomerID();
}

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String result = "";
            //System.out.print("Test 1: ");
            result = test1() ? "pass." : "failed.";
            System.out.println(result);
                    //System.out.print("Test 2: ");
            result = test2() ? "pass." : "failed.";
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
```

Here is code I've written:

```
public class Customer {

    public static final int MAX_ACCOUNTS = 5;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int customerID;
    private BankAccount[] accounts;
    private int numAccounts;
    private static int nextCustomerID = 1;

    //default constructor
    public Customer() {
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
        customerID = 1;
        accounts = null;
        numAccounts = 0;
        nextCustomerID = 1;
    }

    //Constructor sets name and initialized values
    //@param first is the first name
    //@param last is the last name
    public Customer (String first, String last)
    {
        this.firstName = first;
        this.lastName = last;
        this.customerID = 1;
        Customer.nextCustomerID = 1;

    }    

    public String getFirst(){
        return firstName;

    }
    public String getLast(){
        return lastName;
    }


    public String getName ()
    {
        return String.format("%s,%s", getFirst(),getLast());

    }
    public int getCustomerID ()
    {
        return customerID;

    }

}
```

When I run the driver it returns failed. I can't seem to see why, everything seems to be in place correctly. The only thing I can think of is a problem with `String.format`

Comment: Should be `%s %s`, not `%s,%s`

Comment: Is it because Formatters are not necessarily safe for multithreaded access?

Comment: No, because the way your names should be formatted like `Alice Smith`, not `Alice,Smith`

Comment: Andrew Li, why can't I have a comma there? I was under the impression anything can be put in quotations, even if I wanted to put `:`

Comment: But you are comparing `Alice Smith` to `Alice,Smith` of course it is going to return false... it has to be `%s %s` with just a space, no comma

Comment: the test still failed after comma removal. I don't think it's a problem to have `,` there in the first place anyways.

Comment: Yes it was a problem. The next problem is that you don't show your `getCustomerID` method.

Comment: Andrew Li, my mistake I have added the method in.

Comment: The problem is that 1 is not 0. You never initialize `customerID` in any of the constructors so it defaults to 0. Now in your driver, `customerCounter` is incremented so it's 1. 1 != 0 so the test fails. Increment `customerCounter` after.

Comment: Andrew Li, the driver cannot be modified.

Comment: Then modify *both* your constructors to initialize customerID to 1 to start.

Comment: Andrew Li, I have added in another test that tests for creation of 2 customer this one failed.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Is `customerID` based on instance count? If so you may need to make it static and increment on instantiation

Comment: Andrew Li, should I increment in both constructors?

Comment: Andrew Li, I have updated my question by adding the initialization of `nextCustomerID` in my constructors.